# How to install the nouveau drivers on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, kernel, xorg

Because of a bug in nouveaus drivers I switched to nvidia drivers which didn't have that bug. Though now the two newest kernel versions don't boot anymore(just a black screen and a frozen mouse) and I have to revert to the older kernel 5.8.0-59-generic to boot normally. I would like to get the newest kernel version to work and I suspect it's the nvidia drivers responsible for freezing the system. Now when going to Ubuntu's UI under Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers I can select Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source) now when I select it and hit apply changes I get following error message:

```
pk-client-error-quark: The following packages have unmet dependencies: libllvm11: 
Depends: libatomic1 (>=4.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libedit2 (>=2.11-20080614-0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libffi7 (>=3.3~20180313) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6(>=9) but it is not going to be installed
libxdamage1: Depends: libx11-6 (>=2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
(268)
```

How can I fix this issue and install nouveau drivers? Why is it not going to be installed? That seems like a strange error message

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your package lists, then upgrade your system, and try again, this time installing it from the terminal?

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Comment: Running the first two commands finishes without error. The last command gives me: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau is already the newest version (1:1.0.16-1). It's installed but not used. How can I use these drivers? Switching over the gui doesn't work as described above

Comment: Can you try using Additional Drivers again now?

Comment: Same error messages

Comment: Same problem with third command. I can't login on Ubuntu 20.04, I'm locked on black screen