# Ubuntu 22.04 Black screen with Nvidia Geforce RTX 2060

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I have a problem with my new ubuntu 22.04 OS; When the boot is started, I see these errors, and the screen will be black:

```
[    4.817217] usbhid 1-11:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[    7.498381] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[    8.677918] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    8.677921] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    8.677927] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
[    9.705924] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
[   10.710003] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
[   10.715417] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[   10.718884] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Cannot probe codecs, giving up
[   31.022834] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.022873] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.022889] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.022903] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.355003] audit: type=1107 audit(1660548081.503:130): pid=796 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="SessionRemoved" name=":1.26" mask="receive" pid=2013 label="snap.skype.skype" peer_pid=812 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   31.355007] audit: type=1420 audit(1660548081.503:131): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[   31.452304] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.452479] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.452580] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.452668] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.490017] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.490076] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.490098] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.490118] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.552243] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.552418] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.552519] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   31.552606] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

My graphic card is : Nvidia Geforce RTX 2060

Ubuntu kernel version is: 5.15.0-46-generic

ubuntu version is: 22.04

Nvidia driver is?:`nvidia-driver-515, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04)` 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can either 1. Disable Secure Boot in UEFI (don't if dual-booting with Windows 11) or 2. Use mokutil to sign the Nvidia drivers

Comment: Same problem: [    8.677918] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    8.677921] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    8.677927] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110  seems to me to be something about MSI motherboard and USB-C devices, maybe try unplugging any USBC devices you have plugged in?  Just guesses at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after installing `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` through apt, with Ubuntu 22.04 + Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060. I eventually repaired the drivers by opening a terminal at the black screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --fix-missing
sudo apt install --fix-broken
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

followed by a reboot, then clicking the gear icon on the login screen and selecting `Ubuntu` (Xorg), NOT `Ubuntu Wayland` or anything that involves `Wayland`, and finally logging in.

If that doesn't work, you can try

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Credit to these sources for helping me solve the problem.

- [Installing nouveau drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356946/how-to-install-the-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [Nvidia developer forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/the-dreaded-black-screen-on-boot-ubuntu-22-04-2080ti-515-drivers/219837/10)
- [Rafa Rafael's blog](https://rafaelogic.medium.com/fix-ubuntu-22-black-screen-before-login-nvidia-drivers-issue-cfe07783c984)
- [Installing GeForce drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005153/what-nvidia-driver-do-i-need-for-gefroce-920m-and-how-can-i-install-it)
- [Differences between drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)